# Can't get .htaccess to redirect to 404.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I don't know what more I need to configure for the `.htaccess` to work.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I have it in my document root `/var/www/html` where the 404.html is, but it doesn't work.

I tried editing apache2.conf,

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

a suggestion I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache), but when I entered a non-existent page I got an Internal Server Error 500, so I had to change `AllowOverride All` back to `None`.

Everything I look at tells me the same things, but nothing's working for me. This is on a new dedicated server, so it might be something I need to configure in apache2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _“I got an Internal Server Error 500, so I had to […]”_ … yes, check the error log, of course.

Comment: @CBroe - This is embarrassing. What I failed to mention in my post was that I also had 'AllowOverride All` at the head of the `.htaccess`. But I took that out and forgot about it. So when I made the same change in `apache2.conf`, it was giving me the error 500. I changed `apache2.conf` back to `AllowOverride All` and it works. Thanks for reminding me to check the error log.