# I can't use <Files> tag in apache to prevent my file from others' access

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress, now. And today I find out that my xmlrpc.php file is enabled. Now, I want disable it. But what I do below does't work

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Actually， all *.php files won't work using this way. But, if the files don't end with .php, it works

```
<Files "test.txt">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

this is my .htaccess file , and I try write it in httpd.conf too, same result

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "php_test.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "test.txt">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

[test.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMD35.jpg)

I got this when I visit test.txt in my server.
But the php_test.php I got this picture

[php_test.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQP0o.jpg)

I have tried many ways to slove this , now I need help , thank you guys

Comment: i had try your `htaccess` file but it's work

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/disable-xml-rpc-requests  like this , how <Files> works ? thanks

Comment: @Parth Chavda  is there any other settings cause this problem?

Comment: yes it's work for core php as well as wordpres

Comment: may be this will hekp you https://wordpress.org/support/topic/xmlrpcphp-attack-on-wordpress-38

Comment: @ParthChavda  backup and delete this file or add "add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');" in the wp-config.php can slove this. But what I want to know is why only .php files don't work with <Files> tag. Could you please help me some more? is there any setting affect this ?  My English not good enough to look through what you have given me so fast.

Answer (score 0):

I have alternative solution put below code in site related plugin.

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

Comment: yes, thank you ,I find this a little early.But why <Files> tag does't work with my .php files. Do you know that? Thanks

Comment: which server you used ?

Comment: have you enabled rewrite mode ? @weizhengxing because in my site it's work great

Comment: apache , sure I enable it. Now , I going to use my virtual machine, try to find what's different. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Simply, I add   "<Files "php_test.php"> Order Deny,Allow Deny from all</Files>"  in httpd.conf on my virtual machine , it works. But I still don't know what's wrong with my server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache @weizhengxing

Comment: Hello, today I find this, I use php-fpm in my apache server. When I comment out "ProxyPassMatch^/(.*\.php)$fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/wordpress/$1" in "<VirtualHost *:80>" tag. I try it again. It works. Now what should I do to disable the access to .php files, many thanks.I mean in the config files. Sure, it can be done use regular expression. I'm a stubborn guy.

Comment: I find the same question here        http://serverfault.com/questions/618954/apache-2-4-php-fpm-proxypassmatch-and-access-restriction

Comment: @weizhengxing you have found out proper solution please put your answer here and accept that....these will also help to other.

Answer (score 0):

@Parth Chavda

```
ProxyPass /xmlrpc.php !
```

Put the code above in front of your the code below in the `<Virtual Host *80>`tag

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/wordpress/$1
```

And try to visit http://www.yourdomin.com/xmlrpc.php, you get this!!!!

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /xmlrpc.php on this server
```

This problem get fixed.Thanks for the help from  Parth Chavda.

Comment: @Parth Chavda   Finally I get this problem fixed.