# redirecting www. to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My website url looks like *www.[site-name].com*

I want to redirect to *https://www.[site-name].com* on .htaccess with following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
```

I copy the file to ftp at this path: `httpdocs/.htaccess`

[image: img]

But it does not redirect to *[site-name].com* when I try to load *www.[site-name].com*. How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What is happening?

Comment: It does not redirect to https://www.[site-name].com  when i try to load www.[site-name].com

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]
```

Comment: Web page still staying on www.[site-name].com  not redirecting.

Comment: @Onur Would you like to redirect to https or www?

Comment: I want to redirect to https.

Comment: @Onur Are you testing on a real server or localhost?

Comment: Testing on real server not localhost.

Comment: @Onur Then check this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137857/discussion-between-luca-jung-and-onur).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect non-www url to www url , for both http and https use this ;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect www to non-www url use this ;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or without using domainname ;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you wish to redirect http to https just change target from http:// to https:// in directives  below the HTTP_HOST lines