# .htaccess not working in Ubuntu 16

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force redirect my non http and non www site to https with www.

My `.htaccess` file code is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also the rewrite mode is enabled on the server and in apache2.conf file `AllowOverride` is set to `ALL`

But the redirect is not happening. Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Add some garbage characters on a line by itself in the ``.htaccess`` file. Does Apache then give an error? If it doesn't, for a start, the file isn't even being read.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes, i get 500 internal error. That means the .htaccess is working. But the code i am using is correct

Comment: Check the perfect solution from the link on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/51688946/4880531