# How to remove index.php in url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

why not working to remove index.php using htaccess

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule !.*.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Give an example of a URL you want to rewrite, and explain what happens instead of what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: This helped me once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache