# Gzip compression is not working even if it's enabled on the server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have installed php7 with apache2 modules :-

[image]

I have also tested php.ini file, it also shows `gzip:enabled`
[image]

Then I have enable GZIP Compression via .htaccess **source**: https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

But Gzip Compression is stil not working

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Or to put it a different way, what are you seeing that shows it is not working?

Comment: I have tested on https://gtmetrix.com/ it shows that Gzip is not enabled.

Comment: [Is Apache configured to read `.htaccess`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache)

Comment: Yes, I have put some junk in .htacces then website got an internal server error and when removed it worked fine, so that means .htaccess is configured to read by Apache

Answer (score 0):

Try add this mod_gzip conf in .htaccess, maybe it help:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```