# .htaccess file does not work on plesk while it is working on local host

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost, plesk, issue-tracking

I have developed a website in PHP on localhost within XAMPP and now I've uploaded the website to the plesk hosting. Everything is working fine except for the .htaccess file. Either the .htaccess file is not able to work with plesk server OR something else would be the issue.

Is there anybody who can tell me why the .htaccess file is not working on plesk hosting? My .htaccess inside code is here:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://*****/404.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code is working fine on localhost but not on plesk server. Even it is not redirecting the 404 error to the 404 custom page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess not working apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache)

Comment: You should contact your host provider, aparently `AllowOverride` is set to None

Comment: Does your "plesk hosting" run Apache?

Comment: kerbh0lz I don't know if they runs Apache.

Comment: Well, you try to use an apache specific distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but aren't certain that this actually _is_ an apache http server? As already said by others: go and contact your hosting provider. Only they can tell.

Comment: alright arkascha, I already got that and being in contact with the hosting provider. Thanks to all of you.