# How to enable .htaccess in apache2 (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying to use .htaccess on my project on apache2 using ubuntu 18.04.
The tutorials I saw said that I have to change apache2.conf as:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

After change it, I make my own htaccess on project but it doesn't work.
I want browser prevent user to go backward and browsing project directories and my computer directories using URL ../../../../

Ex: localhost/project/index.php/../../../../

How can I use my .htaccess in my project?, knowing that there is no default .htaccess file !
And how to prevent user for browsing directories using ../../ in url ???

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19396579/7993505

Comment: It's not clear, I don't understand him !
.htaccess working now but in my project it return me to parent folder !

Comment: Those are two completely separate questions. Enabling the interpretation of distributed coniguration files and file system access don't have much to do with each other...

Comment: Do you want only permit access to /var/www/project directory ?